# Possible Access To Modified Closure Issue... How To Beat?

Tags: javascript, closures

For some reason no matter what, the pageNumber ends up being the last value in the loop for the loopCounter.  Now I would understand that if I were directly using loopCounter in the closure itself, but I'm not.  As you can see from the code below, I am creating a new variable within the closure to take the current value of loopCounter.

Only thing I can figure is (Assuming that javascript treats everything as a reference type) that pageNumber is taking the reference to loopCounter so no matter how many times I create a new pageNumber, it's always pointing at the loopCounter object.  Therefore, whatever value loopCounter ends up with will be the value any pageNumber will point to.

How do I get it to not point at loopCounter but create a new pageNumber per iteration that holds the current loopCounter value?

```
for (var loopCounter = result.StartingPoint; loopCounter <= result.HighestPageCount; loopCounter++)
{
  ...
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  ...
  //trying to remove the reference to loopCounter
  var pageNumber = loopCounter;
  newDiv.onclick = 
    function(event) 
    { //Right here ---V
      getResultUsingUrl(result.PagerPreLink + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber);
    };

  ...
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to a couple answers below:

```
function createClickMethod(loopCounter, link)
{
    var pageNumber = loopCounter;

    return function(event) { getResultUsingUrl(link + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber); };
}
```

and I can call like:

```
newDiv.onclick = createClickMethod(loopCounter, result.PagerPreLink);
```

Or if I want to use jQuery... suggested below:

```
jQuery(newDiv).click
(
    createClickMethod(loopCounter, result.PagerPreLink)
);
```

Comment: What is result.StartingPoint?

Comment: Eh a an object returned from a asynchronous method call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like everyone else said, it's a scoping problem. Without using a JS library, you can do something like this:

```
newDiv.onclick = (function() {
    var num = loopCounter;
    return function(evt) {
        console.log( num );
    }
})();
```

You just need to create another closure around the value.

Comment: So basically I need a method to create the event method to keep the scope clear.

Comment: Yep.  Since JS scope is limited to functions, not blocks you need to create a new function.   This is essentially what the various JS libs force you to do with their event connect methods.

Answer (score 5):

You are not creating a new pageNumber each time. You only have one. Scope in JavaScript does not extend beyond function-scope. Any "var" you declare in a function -- in or out of loops -- works exactly as it would had you declared it right at the top of the function.

http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 2):

Javascript closures store references to their variables, so all of your onclick handlers are using the same variable.

You need to capture the variable in an intermediate function, like this:

```
function buildClickHandler(pageNumber) {
    return function(event)  {    //Create and return a new function
        getResultUsingUrl(result.PagerPreLink + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber);
    }
}
```

Then, use that function to create `onclick` handlers, like this:

```
for (var loopCounter = result.StartingPoint; loopCounter <= result.HighestPageCount; loopCounter++) { 
    //...

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    newDiv.onclick = buildClickHandler(loopCounter);
}
```

Each call to `buildClickHandler` creates a separate closure that has its own variable.

---

As an aside, consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to do DOM manipulation; it's much easier than raw DOM APIs.

In your example, you could write

```
$('<div />').click(buildClickHandler(loopCounter));
```

Comment: Wish I could mark two as correct.  I would most likely use jquery like you suggested, but I wanted this to be generic so more people would answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is result.StartingPoint really a primitive type, e.g. an actual Number type? If not, then perhaps what's happening is that you are getting a reference to that object and then the string concatenation is doing a type-coercion for you. Try this instead:

```
var pageNumber = new Number(loopCounter); // force coercion
```

Comment: Won't this only make pageNumber reference that method and that method still point to loopCounter?

Answer (score 0):

The onclick closure will not maintain its scope, so it won't be able to access result.

Take a look at [dojo.hitch](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/hitch) for an easy and powerful solution, so that you can control its scope.

Comment: And at that point, you can just use dojo.forEach and dojo.connect